# Programmatically add accounts to Android email application

Tags: android

I have been researching but have been unable to find a way to programmatically add email accounts to the default email application on Android. I have consulted some mobile developers and experts and am given to believe that this is not possible. The only alternative is to develop and application to display email (essentially make an email client) to handle this.

Before I give up, just asking the Stackoverflow community if there are any unpublished APIs or alternatives?

Comment: did you find a solution...? :/

Comment: If you found any solutions, Please share. It will help me.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no 'default email application'. The AOSP email application may or may not be included and most carriers include their own. Second, you generally cannot modify third party apps unless they provide some sort of API for this (ContentProvider, etc.). If you want to confirm this for the AOSP Email app, just go through the source. For anything else there are not guarantees, but since email account info is sensitive information, I doubt any of those has public API to modify or query email accounts.

Comment: But there is an API for adding accounts. Why can't one app use it to add an account for another app?